# Trying to debug: _export__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.methods is undefined in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to read a JSON file as a static prop to initialize a method for the project. But the problem is I am getting an error when I try to call the function that calls the method that reads the JSON file.

This is from the component function

```
import Web3 from "web3"
import fs from 'fs'
import buildData from '../../build/contracts/Betting.json'
// export local copies of contracts

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const data =  JSON.stringify(await buildData.abi);
    return {
      props: {data,},
    }
  }


const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RINKEBY_RPC_URL
)
const web3 = new Web3(provider)
const abi = await getStaticProps()

const bettingContract = async (web3) => {
    return new web3.eth.Contract(
        await abi,
        "0x65b01f0f4Ec1885bD00D8C6dC8027fcc1316BCC4"
    )
}

export default bettingContract
```

In my useEffect hook that calls it (EDITED):

```
    useEffect( () => {
        const getPrizeMoneyHandler = async () => {
            const prizeMoney = await bettingContract.methods.getPrizeMoney().call()
            setPrizeMoney(prizeMoney)
        }
        getPrizeMoneyHandler()
        return () => {
            // this now gets called when the component unmounts
        };  
        
    })
```

I get the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: _blockchain_resplendent_contract_export__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.methods is undefined
```

This is specifically when I try to run getPrizeMoneyHandler() in the useEffect hook in the main application file. I know that I am able to retrieve the abi JSON data within the first code block. But I admit I don't know if it comes in time before I export bettingContract. I am going to assume my issue is not being able to call the promise correctly in the useEffect hook.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I looked a tid tad more into my problem and I reworked the use Effect hook to be the above and I still have the error so I don't think it's a promise issue but something up with the first component function at the top, bettingContract. Any ideas to how to debug this?

Comment: `bettingContract` is a function, did you mean to call `const prizeMoney = (await bettingContract()).methods.getPrizeMoney().call()` instead?